# Difference Equation - Time Response analysis of Discrete Systems

Tags: signal-processing

We know that that the difference equation formula for computing an output sample at time `n` is based upon its past/present input samples and past output samples in time domain:

[image]

My question is why `j` begins from 1 rather than from value 0 like for `i` and also how can we write the below output equation in difference equation form:

```
y(n) = 0.01x(n - 5) + 0.002x(n - 1) + 0.99y(n - 1) 
y(n) = 0.01x(n) + 0.002(n - 1) 
y(5) = 0.01x(3) + x(1)
```

Secondly why y(n) sequence values are calculated as a sum of a series of input / output, cause I have been studying that **y(n) = {2,4,6,8}** when **x(n) = {1,2,3,4}** and n **={1,2,3,4}** (example per say) i.e. **y(n) = 2.x(n)**. There was no mention that for y(n) (y(2) say) value we need to add values of x(n) and y(n) i.e. (take values of x(1) or y(1)) or y(n-1))?

Comment: is there a typo in `0.002(n - 1)`? are you missing a `x`?

Comment: the first 2 equations are legit difference equations. The last one is not a diff. equation formula, though you can make one up from it, like `y(n) = 0.01x(n-2) + x(n-4)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand because the index  j starts from 1 , you have to write your original difference equation slightly differently, bring all the y(...) on the LHS: 
y(n)+a1 y(n-1)+....+ aN y(n-N) = b0 x(n) + b1 x(n-1)+...+bM x(n-M)
if you compact the equation with the summation symbol, you'll see that both indexes i and j start from 0. Furthermore you have  a0=1

---

y(n) = 0.01x(n - 5) + 0.002x(n - 1) + 0.99y(n - 1) in difference equation form is:
y(n) - 0.99y(n-1) = 0x(n) + 0.002x(n - 1) +  0x(n-2) +  0x(n-3) +  0x(n-4) +  0.01x(n-5)

Not sure if the other two have difference equation form

---

To understand because y(n) sequence values are calculated as a sum of a series of input / output you can see the problem in this way:
you have a general system with an input x and an output y
Your system has the ability to remember the past input and the past output, this means that if you want to calculate the new output value y(n) you have to use

- the past output y(n-1) y(n-2) ...y(n-N) . In this case your system has a memory of length N for the output
- the present input x(n) and the past input x(n-1) x(n-2) ...x(n-M) . In this case your system has a memory of length M for the input

In general you can have any relationship between the new output y(n) and the past input and output. 
In the very special case (but used a lot)  of a linear time invariant system, the new output y(n)  is just a linear combination of the past input and output (the coefficients  bi and aj are numbers, they are not function of time):

y(n) = -a1 y(n-1) -....- aN y(n-N)  + b0 x(n) + b1 x(n-1)+...+bM x(n-M)

Answer (score 0):

I answer the first part,

> why `j` begins from `1` and not from `0`?

You can always rewrite the expression with `j` starting from zero as a new expression with `j` starting from `1`. Simply:

- take the term with `j=0` out of the summation sign, and then from the RHS to the LHS
- collect `y(n)` at the LHS, and divide by `(1+a_0)`.
- redefine `b_i -> b_i/(1+a_0)` and `a_i -> a_i(1+a_0)`

Now your summation at the RHS starts with `j=1`.

Comment: So we have a new set of coefficients - I hope that they would change the values of the equation when j starts with 0 or 1 or would the answer be same when j is either 0 or 1?

Comment: yes, they would, they are mapped as described above, last line of the bullet points